# Facing problem when using back button in title bar

Tags: android

Friend's I have a problem when click the back button either in device or customised back button in header,it never back to show the list content,it simply shows the blank screen.

For example - -

I have list view - list1,in it's onclick event i move to next listview -list2, and from list2 -onclick event i move to webview there i have back button in my titlebar,when i click it throws null pointer exception even from device back button also getting same,and the list show empty. where my webview is in New Activity.

Here my code for back button onClick, { finish(); } How can i resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant guess. Post some code snippet plz.

Comment: do you have the back button in your activity that contains your webview ? or that back button is in the main activity?

Comment: the back button is in common title bar, it's in header xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

override this method "onBackPressed"

```
public void onBackPressed(){

}
```

and also call this method at back button click...it will bring you to previous activity